# Confused about how to use mock and stubs

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a class and a spec.

```
class Store
  def activate(product_klass, product_id)
    product = product_klass.find(product_id)
    if product.inactive?
      product.update_attribute :active, true
    end
  end
end

describe Store do
  it "should activate an inactive product" do
    product = mock
    product.stub(:inactive?).and_return(true)    
    store = Store.new
    store.activate(22) # 
    product.should be_active
  end
end
```

***Running the spec fails***. I get:

```
Mock received unexpected message :find_by_id with (1)
```

To satisfy that, I add  `product.should_receive(:find_by_id).with(1).and_return(product)` before the line `store.activate(product, 22)`. (This seems the wrong thing to do since I do not want my test to know too much about the internals of the method I am testing)

***Running the spec again***, I get failure, where the following line returns `false` instead of the expected `true`:

```
product.should be_active
```

So, it is returning `false` because `product.update_attribute :active, true` did not really set `active` to `true` : it was just absorbed by the mock.

I have so many questions. How does one go about rspec'cing? How should I have tested this instead? Am I using mocks and stubs correctly?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think the activation logic doesn't belong into `Store` at all. If it were declared in `Product`, the test would look a lot more natural to me:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def activate
    if inactive?
      update_attribute :active, true
    end
  end
end

describe Product do
  it "should activate an inactive product" do
    product = Product.new
    product.activate 
    product.should be_active
  end
end
```

From there you could re-write your `Store` method like this:

```
class Store
  def activate(product_klass, product_id)
    product = product_klass.find(product_id)
    product.activate
  end
end

describe Store do
  it "should activate an inactive product" do
    product = mock
    product.should_receive(:activate)
    product_klass = mock
    product_klass.should_receive(:find).with(22).and_return(product)
    store = Store.new
    store.activate(product_klass, 22)
  end
end
```

Comment: Right, I get the gist. But I don't like the idea that I have to have the line `product_klass.should_receive(:find).with(22).and_return(product)` in there. That seems too intrusive and makes the spec brittle?. If I were to change how the product is fetched, then I have to change the spec as well.

Comment: Well it is quite important for the logic of the method how the record is fetched, isn't it? Maybe you could extract this into a separate method that fetches records based on their type (class) and keep `Store.activate` simpler. Also check first, if you even need to have a method `activate` in `Store` or if you can call it directly on the `Product`.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @padde about the fact that the product activation should be on the `Product` model, as so:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def activate
    if inactive?
      update_attribute :active, true
    end
  end
end
```

However, I would refactor the test to bring it inline with Rspec standard practices:

```
describe Product do
  context "after activating" do   # Human readable situation of the test
    let(:product) { Product.new.activate }
    subject { product }           # Make product the subject of the test

    it { should be_active }       # Product should be active
  end
end
```

And the `Store` test:

```
describe Store do
  context "when activating a product" do
    let(:product)       { mock }
    let(:store)         { Store.new }

    before do
      product_klass = double                 # Stub the product class, don't mock
      product_klass.stub(:find) { product }  # We want to test product here, not the class
      store.activate(product_klass, 22)
    end

    subject { product }                      # product is the subject again

    it { should_receive(:activate) }         # it should receive the activate message
  end
end
```

I removed the expectation on `product_klass`, as that's not really what you're interested in testing in this case. You might like that as a separate test.

Using `let`, `subject` and `context` arranges your tests in a standard way, and allows rspec to do some neat things like produce human-friendly documentation of your classes. For more on rspec best practices, take a look at [betterspecs](http://betterspecs.org/).